# How to make Postfix able to send message to the world?

Tags: postfix, smtp, postgresql

I'm configuring a SMTP server based on Postfix with PostgreSQL. When I try to send a mail to another domain I got a **Recipient address rejected: Access denied** error.

Here is my configuration :

```
# postconf -n

alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
local_recipient_maps = 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = lan.example.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = lan.example.com
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_auth_destination, reject
virtual_alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql.d/virtual_alias.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:108
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/postfix/incoming
virtual_mailbox_domains = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql.d/virtual_domain.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 51200000
virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql.d/virtual_mailbox.cf
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:105
```

Here, *example.com* is the domain name of the server, and *lan.example.com* is the domain name of the relay host.

Here is the complete error :

```
Oct 15 10:22:08 authentification postfix/smtpd[9930]: connect from unknown[10.1.250.173]
Oct 15 10:22:08 authentification postfix/smtpd[9930]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[10.1.250.173]: 554 5.7.1 <david.jose.delassus@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: Access denied; from=<noreply@example.com> to=<david.jose.delassus@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<localhost>
Oct 15 10:22:08 authentification postfix/smtpd[9930]: lost connection after RSET from unknown[10.1.250.173]
Oct 15 10:22:08 authentification postfix/smtpd[9930]: disconnect from unknown[10.1.250.173]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not misunderstanding your question, you want to send mail through `lan.example.com`. If `lan.example.com` is the same box, `relayhost = lan.example.com` should not be set (as this is already the relay host).

From the [postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_relay_restrictions)

```
By default, the Postfix SMTP server accepts:

  Mail from clients whose IP address matches $mynetworks, or
  Mail to remote destinations that match $relay_domains, except for addresses
   that contain sender-specified routing (user@elsewhere@domain), or
  Mail to local destinations that match $inet_interfaces or $proxy_interfaces,
    $mydestination, $virtual_alias_domains, or $virtual_mailbox_domains.
```

You should specify the network `10.1.250.0/24` (or whatever bit mask) to be part of `$mynetworks`, or, specifically put it into `smtpd_relay_restrictions`:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = $mynetworks, 10.1.250.0/24
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was solved by adding ``10.0.0.0/8`` to ``$mynetworks``

Comment: `smtpd_relay_restrictions` is new to postfix 2.10, which is still under development. Apart from that, this setting does not accept lists of hosts or IP ranges - it accepts only **restrictions**. You may be thinking of `relay_domains`, or something else.

Comment: @adaptr: you are mistaken. If you do not specify `smtpd_relay_restrictions` it defaults to `$mynetworks, reject`. You just have to try it to be sure ;). `relay_domains` only suits you for relaying mail for specific domains.

Comment: $mynetworks is not a valid restriction.